# GET Image from API Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, single-page-application

I am trying to get logo image(any type image, example: jpeg, png, gif) from API I can see image in Network tab but console throws an error as shown in attached image. Any suggestions? I am using htppclient.get and .toPromise() to and Angular latest version.

edit: I also have this header set

```
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.getHeaders().append('responseType', 'text');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answer given below helped me but in my case I was not crating image so once I do GET I  than created image and it helped me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you are receiving 'blob' type from your request you have to change your headers accordingly. Try changing the accept-type from json to image format. Check below code and see if that helps

```
getImage() {
    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
         .set('Accept', "image/webp,*/*");

    return this.http.get<Blob>(url, { headers: httpHeaders, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' });
}
```

After this you can create the image from this data.

Comment: My header was good but I was missing to create image from that. My issue is resolved by creating image. Thank you for your comment that helped me to find out what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

You should return you http code like this. Blob is the type you want to deal with when working with image file

```
getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
  return this.httpClient.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

You can view this blog [post](https://blog.strongbrew.io/safe-image-requests-in-angular/) for more detail

Comment: It shows this error now inside of code.

Type '"blob"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.ts(2322)
client.d.ts(1075, 9): The expected type comes from property 'responseType' which is declared here on type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'